# Can I have per-project Yeoman generators?

Tags: node.js, yeoman, package.json

I have a Node project and I wanted to make a custom generator of components for this specific project.

I got it working by creating the generator as a separate package, but that's inconvenient - now I have to manage versioning of two packages instead of one, and rely on `yarn link` for development.

```
my-project/
    src/
        ...
    package.json
        {   
            ...
            "devDependencies": {
                "my-project-generator": "file:../my-project-generator"
            ]
        }
my-project-generator/
    generators/
        ...
    package.json
        {
            ...
            "keywords": ["yeoman-generator"]
        }
```

Is there a way to keep the generator inside the project itself? I tried this but `yo` didn't discover the generator.

```
my-project/
    src/
        ...
    generators/
        ...
    package.json
        {   
            "keywords": ["yeoman-generator"]
            ...
        }
```

Comment: You could run generator by file path `yo ./generators/my-generator/index.js`

Comment: @YuryTarabanko thanks, that solved my problem! can you post as an answer so that I can accept?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following this [issue](https://github.com/yeoman/environment/issues/11) you could run generators by file path

```
yo ./generators/path/to/local/file.js
```